# Sign a transaction hash using JavaScript

Tags: transactions, javascript, signature, hash

Which JavaScript library should I use to sign a transaction hash? I don’t want to sign a transaction object. I simply want to sign the hash so I'll have a signature, not a signed transaction object.

Answer (score 1):

After a little deeper research I've found how this is done using the [secp256k1](https://github.com/cryptocoinjs/secp256k1-node) library in the [ethereumjs-util](https://github.com/ethereumjs/ethereumjs-util) code:

```
const sig = secp256k1.sign(msgHash, privateKey)
```

Where `msgHash` is a Buffer containing the transaction hash. `sig.signature` is the signature hex code.

Code found [here](https://github.com/ethereumjs/ethereumjs-util/blob/master/index.js#L329)